# Cannot Load This URL in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I want to open glauniversity.in in my webview. I have implemented following code and searched a lot, but everything seems futile. Any Help will be Appreciated. The code goes as follows:

```
public class WebViews extends Activity {
String link;
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        link="glauniversity.in";

        webview = findViewById(R.id.wv);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { @Override public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) { return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result); } });
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl(link);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                        webview.goBack();
                    }
                    else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It Displays Nothing. I thought that webview can't open webpages which have popups in it (glauniversity.in has popups in beginning), i loaded google.com and then opened glauniversity.in and it shows up perfectly.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that refers to a webpage.

Comment: `webview.loadUrl(link);`. Your `link` is not an url is it? It could as well be a file name. Or a car mark. Or the title of a book.

Comment: didn't get that. Is glauniversity.in not an URL?

Comment: No. It misses a protocol description to begin with.

Comment: `glauniversity.in` will be a server on the internet. Which language does it speak? FTP?

Comment: I understand that. So why it opens up when opened up by google.com in webview? Is webview designed to take only http or Https websites?

Comment: Is there no way i can add this in my webview? This is a small module in my app and if there is any trick i can use, please share.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. And it is unclear if you understood that you forgot the protocol. Difficult talking in this way. Please post a new value for your 'link'.

Answer (score 0):

`glauniversity.in`, This is not a valid url

replace this to

```
http://glauniversity.in/
```

**Bonus**::

Check valid url by

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()
```

or

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```